# Cumulus not working on elementary os loki

Tags: release-loki, gtk, thirdpartyapps

Cumulus, a popular weather app for linux isn't working on loki. it doesn't launch from `slingshot-launcher` and when i invoke it from terminal this comes back :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cumulus", line 48, in <module>
    import cumulus
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cumulus/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk # pylint: disable=E0611
ImportError: No module named gi.repository
```

Anyone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you installed it, but it looks like you are missing the `python-gobject` package which is used by Python to interact with GTK.

You can install it with `sudo apt install python-gobject`.

Comment: installed it via cumulus PPA.

Answer (score 0):

Mike Wild's solution also works in Juno. I checked my installed packages and **python-gobject-2** was installed (not sure which app installed it or if it's part of Juno). Once I installed **python-gobject**, then Cumulus worked.